# Оформление нумерованного списка

Tags: html, css

Делаю нумерованный список наподобие того, что рассмотрен в первом примере вот [по этой ссылке](http://www.xiper.net/collect/html-and-css-tricks/content/custom-ol.html). Все получилось, все работает, но в том куске стилей, который прописывается для IE6, 7 есть какая-то ошибка, но я не могу понять, где:

```
.main ol {
z-index: expression(
    runtimeStyle.zIndex = 1,
    function(node) {
        var list = node.childNodes, i = list.length;
            while(i--) {
                if(list[i].nodeType == 1) {
                    list[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<div>'+(i+1)+'</div>');
                }
            }
        }(this));
    )
}
.main ol div {
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 6px;
    background: #FF0000;
    width: 20px;
    padding: 3px 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

подскажите?

Comment: Проверяли, их пример в IE7 работает? http://www.xiper.net/examples/html-and-css-tricks/content/custom-ol.html

Comment: неа, оказалось, тоже не работает, проверяла в ие-тестере. в общем, оно более менее отрабатывает, если разнести примерно код так http://jsfiddle.net/afmYr/, но добиться того, что мне надо, у меня пока не получается.

Comment: лучше ЗАБУДЬ про IE6-7 !!! они умерли, если нет- то нужно их добить (просто не адаптируя под них контент). Удали костыли и все будет работать на современных браузерах

Answer (score 1):

После `runtimeStyle.zIndex = 1,` вместо запятой поставить ;

Comment: Неа, все равно не работает